# Forbidden error Google+ API

Tags: google-plus, google-oauth

I am trying to get list of user friends using browser API Key using Google-plus api like this -  `https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/112164489692089126102/people/visible?key={Browser-API-KEy}`

But i m getting this error -

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "forbidden",
    "message": "Forbidden"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Forbidden"
 }
}
```

Using access_token its working fine -

```
https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/112164489692089126102/people/visible?access_token={access-token}
```

How to use API-KEY instead of access token to get user data ?

Answer (score 1):

People.list requires the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login` which is only usable when authenticating as a user. You have to make the request as a user and not as an application.

Comment: But the access token provided by the google+ api, expires in 3600 secs. Also if I add `'access_type': 'offline','approval_prompt': 'auto' `  then on every sign in , the permission prompt appears. How to refresh_token or get a long lived token ?

Comment: Access_type=offline is bnow you get a long lived token.